# problem in libvirt service with g_hash_table_unref?

Tags: virtualization, opensuse, libvirt

libvirt service always show this error, when i take status of libvirt service.

```
g_hash_table_unref: assertion 'hash_table != NULL' failed
```

the whole status of libvirt service:

**

```
libvirtd.service always show this error when i take libvirt service status:
libvirtd.service - Virtualization daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/libvirtd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2024-01-07 09:40:14 +0330; 22min ago
TriggeredBy: ● libvirtd-admin.socket
             ● libvirtd.socket
             ● libvirtd-ro.socket
       Docs: man:libvirtd(8)
             https://libvirt.org
   Main PID: 5659 (libvirtd)
      Tasks: 21 (limit: 32768)
     CGroup: /system.slice/libvirtd.service
             └─ 5659 /usr/sbin/libvirtd --timeout 120
Jan 07 09:40:14 mailNew systemd[1]: Starting Virtualization daemon...
Jan 07 09:40:14 mailNew systemd[1]: Started Virtualization daemon.
Jan 07 09:42:22 mailNew libvirtd[5659]: g_hash_table_unref: assertion 'hash_table != NULL' failed
```

**

what should i do for this problem?

Comment: Just ran into the very same issue.